# Nginx case insensitive proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've got a site called `http://example.com`, with an app running that can be accessed at `http://example.com/app1`. The app1 is sitting behind an nginx reverse proxy, like so:

```
location /app1/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Adding the trailing slash to the `proxy_pass` field lets me "remove" the /app1/ part of the URL, at least as far as the app is concerned. So app1 thinks that it's getting requests to the root url (as in, I have a route in app1 that sits on `'/'`, not `'/app1'`).

However, I'd like to have nginx make this case-insensitive. So whether I go to `http://example.com/App1` or `http://example.com/APP1`, it should still just forward the request to app1, *and* remove the /app1/ part of the url.

When I attempt to use nginx's case insensitive rules, it does not let forward the rest of the URI to app1.

```
location ~* /app1/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

That gives me an nginx configuration error.

My goals are two fold:

- Match `/app1/` case insensitively
- Remove the `/app1/` part of the url when "passing" the url over to the app

I've tried rewriting the url, but it won't let me add the rest of the URI to proxy_pass.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should capture rest of the url and then use it

```
location ~* /app1/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: I get a 502 bad gateway when trying that

Comment: Actually it was my issue, nginx errors showed `*502 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client:`. I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and it worked. Thanks!