# Nginx location doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, redirect, nginx, location, vps

I have two angular projects in my VPS, the main project is found at **/home/first_app/**, the second one is at **/home/second_app/**

This is my nginx conf:

```
server_name www.my_domain.com my_domain.com

location /second_app {
    alias /home/second_app/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

location / {
    root /home/first_app/dist;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}
```

The first app works well but I cannot access to the second app by using: **mydomain.com/second_app**. It always took the **/** location block.

In the debug log, I found:

```
test location "/"
test location "second_app"
use configuration "/"
```

Thanks !

Comment: Can you try to move first location section (location /second_app) to second position?

Answer (score -1):

First of all plz create a dist build.

Using Angular CLI.

`$ng build --prod`

after that try using a local server on your *dist/* folder. you cant install nws.

`npm install -g nws`

and run

`nws`

and go to this url. http://localhost:3030

if you see your apps running fine you can discard its. after that maybe you can follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320674/how-can-i-have-same-rule-for-two-locations-in-nginx-config).

Well, i hope this can be handy.

Comment: This by no means resolves the issue in question, the resolution or answer should be related to a proper configuration in nginx not using a build server or proxy.