# How to redirect multiple files in same directory using nginx?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, nginx

We have a site built with WordPress with `nginx` web server. I want to do multiple redirection in one line of code in our `nginx` file.

The code below runs smoothly:

```
location /wp-links-opml.php {
  return 301 https://$host/page-not-found;
}
```

What I want to happen is redirect multiple files in just one config:

```
location /wp-links-opml.php /wp-config-sample.php /wp-load.php {
  return 301 https://$host/page-not-found;
}
```

All of the files above belong in `root` directory but `nginx` prompts with `nginx exited with code 1`

Do you know how can I properly redirect multiple files in 1 config?

**Note**: I tried this [How can I have same rule for two locations in NGINX config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320674/how-can-i-have-same-rule-for-two-locations-in-nginx-config) but in my case I am working with php files and not locations

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you could use one location for multiple files:

```
    location ~ ^/(wp-links-opml.php|wp-config-sample.php|wp-load.php)$ {
        return 301 https://$host/page-not-found;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this. what i also did with your code is put the new config on top of the default `nginx` php config. i think it has an effect in terms of priority