# Guide on how to use regex in Nginx location block section?

Tags: regex, nginx, regex-group, nginx-location, nginx-config

**Nginx regex location syntaxe**

Regex expressions can be used with Nginx location block section, this is implemented with the PCRE engine.

What does exactly this feature support as it is not fully documented?

Answer (score 230):

## Nginx location:

Nginx location block section have a search order, a modifier, an implicit match type and an implicit switch to whether stop the search on match or not. the following array describe it for regex.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Search-Order       Modifier       Description                                                        Match-Type        Stops-search-on-match
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     1st               =           The URI must match the specified pattern exactly                  Simple-string              Yes
#     2nd               ^~          The URI must begin with the specified pattern                     Simple-string              Yes
#     3rd             (None)        The URI must begin with the specified pattern                     Simple-string               No
#     4th               ~           The URI must be a case-sensitive match to the specified Rx      Perl-Compatible-Rx      Yes (first match)                 
#     4th               ~*          The URI must be a case-insensitive match to the specified Rx    Perl-Compatible-Rx      Yes (first match)
#     N/A               @           Defines a named location block.                                   Simple-string              Yes
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Capturing group:

Capturing group, expression evaluation `()` are supported, this example `location ~ ^/(?:index|update)$` match url ending with *example.com/index* and *example.com/update*

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    ()    : Group/Capturing-group, capturing mean match and retain/output/use what matched
#            the patern inside (). the default bracket mode is "capturing group" while (?:) 
#            is a non capturing group. example (?:a|b) match a or b in a non capturing mode
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#    ?:    : Non capturing group
#    ?=    : Positive look ahead 
#    ?!    : is for negative look ahead (do not match the following...)
#    ?<=   : is for positive look behind
#    ?<!   : is for negative look behind
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## The forward slash:

Not to confuse with the regex slash `\`, In nginx the forward slash `/` is used to match any sub location including none example `location /`. In the context of regex support the following explanation apply

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     /    : It doesn't actually do anything. In Javascript, Perl and some other languages, 
#            it is used as a delimiter character explicitly for regular expressions.
#            Some languages like PHP use it as a delimiter inside a string, 
#            with additional options passed at the end, just like Javascript and Perl.
#            Nginx does not use delimiter, / can be escaped with \/ for code portability 
#            purpose BUT this is not required for nginx / are handled literally 
#            (don't have other meaning than /)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## The slash:

The first purpose of the regex special character `\` is meant to escape the next character; But note that in most case `\` followed by a character have a different meaning, a complete list is [available here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Nginx does not require escaping the forward slash `/` it does not either deny escaping it like we could escape any other character. and thus `\/` is translated/matching `/`. One purpose of escaping forward slashes in the context of nginx could be for code portability.

## Other regex chars

Here is a non exhaustive list of regex expression that can be used

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     ~     : Enable regex mode for location (in regex ~ mean case-sensitive match)
#     ~*    : case-insensitive match
#     |     : Or
#     ()    : Match group or evaluate the content of ()
#     $     : the expression must be at the end of the evaluated text 
#             (no char/text after the match) $ is usually used at the end of a regex 
#             location expression. 
#     ?     : Check for zero or one occurrence of the previous char ex jpe?g
#     ^~    : The match must be at the beginning of the text, note that nginx will not perform 
#             any further regular expression match even if an other match is available 
#             (check the table above); ^ indicate that the match must be at the start of 
#             the uri text, while ~ indicates a regular expression match mode.
#             example (location ^~ /realestate/.*)
#             Nginx evaluation exactly this as don't check regexp locations if this 
#             location is longest prefix match.
#     =     : Exact match, no sub folders (location = /)
#     ^     : Match the beginning of the text (opposite of $). By itself, ^ is a 
#             shortcut for all paths (since they all have a beginning).
#     .*    : Match zero, one or more occurrence of any char
#     \     : Escape the next char
#     .     : Any char 
#     *     : Match zero, one or more occurrence of the previous char
#     !     : Not (negative look ahead)
#     {}    : Match a specific number of occurrence ex. [0-9]{3} match 342 but not 32
#             {2,4} match length of 2, 3 and 4
#     +     : Match one or more occurrence of the previous char 
#     []    : Match any char inside
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Examples:

```
location ~ ^/(?:index)\.php(?:$|/)
```

```
location ~ ^\/(?:core\/img\/background.png|core\/img\/favicon.ico)(?:$|\/)
```

```
location ~ ^/(?:index|core/ajax/update|ocs/v[12]|status|updater/.+|oc[ms]-provider/.+)\.php(?:$|/)
```

Comment: More one regex char, the "any not inside", `[^xyz]` = all that is not xyz

Comment: even NGINX official website and documents do not offer such a detailed & comprehensive guide of regular expression used in NGINX.  thanks for your great efforts.

Comment: @intika Thanks a ton for this ! Do you also have examples where capturing groups can be used ? For example to set_request_body in a proxy_pass directive ?

Comment: This site helped me to verify my regex quickly: https://nginx.viraptor.info/

Comment: @RafikFarhad great site, thanks.  And thanks to Sheharyar and intika for the great post.  Cheers to both, jz