# nginx serve file but not all files in dynamic directory

Tags: nginx

i want to serve file on nginx server here's the case below

serve location /home/ubuntu/username/fileName
eg1    /home/ubuntu/john/d1.txt
eg2    /home/ubuntu/john/d2.txt
eg3    /home/ubuntu/kiddo/d3.txt

it is not accessable using.

```
location ~ /home/ubuntu/(?<user>.+)/(?<file>.+)$ {
            root /home/ubuntu/$user/$file;
}
```

[nginx rules on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846238/guide-on-how-to-use-regex-in-nginx-location-block-section)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
location ~ /home/ubuntu/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ {
            root /home/ubuntu/$1/$2;
}
```

Comment: not work. user is pbh.ind & file is queue_.97b7743a-fc46-4da5-ba21-52256df1e6f8.wav

Comment: @patabhu, ok could you please do check now and let me know how it goes?

Comment: not work. Also tried giving permission 755 & owner root.

Comment: @patabhu, ok what is the url you are hitting?

Comment: @patabhu, could you please be more clear on which url you are hitting on browser and which url you want it to rewrite to in backend? That will give me better understanding, thank you.

Comment: https://hostname/home/ubuntu/pbh.ind/queue_.97b7743a-fc46-4da5-ba21-52256df1e6f8.wav file is in same location which url want to access.

Comment: @patabhu, ok then you are trying to match only location?

Comment: yes, trying to match url only with location

Comment: @patabhu, ok please check my edited rule once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228348/discussion-between-patabhu-and-ravindersingh13).