# Access through ingress returns 404

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I installed pods and services with `deployment.yml`,`service.yml` and `ingress.yml` like this below.

`deployment.yml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apa000dep
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apa000kube
  replicas : 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apa000kube
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: apa000ex91
          image: httpd
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

`service.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: apa000ser
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8099
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    app: apa000kube
```

Both works well and, I can access pod directly `localhost:30080`

then i installed ingress.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: demo.localdev.me
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /*
        backend:
          service:
            name: apa000ser
            port:
              number: 8099
```

The hostname is set correctly

```
$kubectl get ingress 
    
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS              ADDRESS   
PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   <none>   demo.localdev.me             80      95m
```

However when I access `http://demo.localdev.me` it returns 404 error.

`http://localhost:30080/` returns `<span>it works!</span>`

So, I guess some ingress setting is wrong. where should I check?

---

Even I stop `example-ingress`, result is same.

So it means.

```
nginx-ingress -> ingress -> service -> pods.
```

Every request is fetchd in first `nginx-ingress`, and not sent to `ingress`?

Comment: I spend some Euro for a domain using local IP address for the entry and let certmanager create a cert with DNS challenge. You can even use external DNS as kubernetes component to set DNS entries automatically. You get next to a real domain name a real certificate to test secure http connections.

Comment: @Manuel Thank you for your comment, when I need https access, I should do something like that, however for now, I am just testing.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that caught my eye:

1. The Ingress controller you are using <del>seems to</del> might require an `ingressClassName` defined in the Ingress resource, so that the ingress controller takes this resource (and its configs) into account.

   More about `Ingress class`:

   - [Ingress class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class)
   - [Default IngressClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-ingress-class)
2. You should change the `path: /*` to `path: /`.

   - `path: /*` makes the Ingress controller create a location block à la

     ```
     location /* {
       ...
     }
     ```

     `/*` is interpreted as a normal prefix in this case and has nothing to do with regex (probably not what you assumed).

     In your case: the *404* comes rather from the ingress itself (since request URI `/` not found - must be '/*' instead). In order for a request to be proxied to the httpd server at all, the request must be as follows: "http://demo.localdev.me/*", to which the httpd would again respond with 404 (since the resource '/*' also doesn't exist on httpd by default).
   - Whereas `path: /` does the following:

     ```
     location / {
       ...
     }
     ```

     The `location /` block is a special case that matches any URI that starts with a slash (/), which includes all URIs. (This is also the default location block that Nginx uses if no other location block matches the request's URI.)

   More about nginx `location`:

   - [nginx doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)
   - [Guide on how to use regex in Nginx location block section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846238/guide-on-how-to-use-regex-in-nginx-location-block-section)

**Final result:**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx   # add
  rules:
  - host: demo.localdev.me
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /           # change
        backend:
          service:
            name: apa000ser
            port:
              number: 8099
```