# nginx: Regex match the middle of a URL and also the ending?

Tags: regex, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an app on a domain that is set by a developer to proxy at certain URLs:

```
example.com/browser/123foo0/stuff.js
```

for example, where `123foo0` is some random key. The key may also change length in future.

That's all fine.

But I'd like to interrupt specific requests and not proxy them: I don't want to serve anything after the key that is in the path `/welcome` for example, i.e. not proxy any of these:

```
example.com/browser/123foo0/welcome/welcome.html
example.com/browser/foo456b/welcome/welcome.css
example.com/browser/bar123f/welcome/welcome.js
example.com/browser/456foob/welcome/other.stuff
example.com/browser/foo789b/welcome/
```

So I tried simple stuff first like: `location ^~ /browser/.*/welcome/welcome.html {...` and `location ~* .*/welcome/ {...`
but couldn't even get that working, before moving on to try capturing groups like css files and scripts and so on.

I also tried putting regex in quotes, but that didn't seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a truncated version of the conf, with the location blocks only:

```
    location ^~ "/browser/.*/welcome/welcome.html" {
        return 200 'Not proxied.\n';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }

    location ^~ /browser {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    # landing page
    location / {
      root /var/www/foobar;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

---

#### Edit

I've reviewed the documentation on [how nginx selects a location](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), but unfortunately I didn't find it particularly clear or helpful. What am I missing?

I thought this rule in question would match and take precedence over the latter `/browser` rule, because of this line in the documentation:

> If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked.

i.e. because this rule in question comes first and it *is longer* than the latter `/browser` rule, a match would occur here and not later (because processing stops here)?

But this is also confusing because I also tried `~* [pattern]` instead of the priority prefix `^~ [pattern]` and that didn't work either...

Comment: `^~` is not a regular expression operator. `location ^~ /browser` will prevent your other regular expressions from working. See [how Nginx selects a location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I checked that link and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846238/guide-on-how-to-use-regex-in-nginx-location-block-section#59846239) but I'm still confused. I'll make an edit to my question to show why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
location ^~ "/browser/.*/welcome/welcome.html" { ... }
location ^~ /browser { ... }
```

which is wrong in two ways:

1. `/browser/.*/welcome/welcome.html` is a regular expression (because of the `.*`), which means it can **only** appear in `location` statements with a `~` or `~*` operators.
2. `location ^~ /browser` will allow a longer matching prefix location, but you cannot use a prefix location because of the `.*`.

---

A better solution would be:

```
location ~ ^/browser/[^/]+/welcome/welcome\.html$ { ... }
location /browser { ... }
```

By using the corrected regular expression statement, and removing the `^~` operator from the prefix location.

Answer (score 3):

```
# 1 regexp location
location ~ ^/browser/.*/welcome/.*$ {
  return 200 'Not proxied.\n';
  add_header Content-Type text/plain;
}
# 2 regexp location
location ~ ^/browser/.* {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003;
}
=========================================
server {
  listen 3003;
...
  location ~ ^/browser/.*$ {
    return 200 'Proxied from $host\n';
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
  }
}
```

check with curl

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3002/browser/KEY/notwelcome/some/path/file.ext
Proxied from 127.0.0.1

$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3002/browser/KEY/welcome/some/path/file.ext
Not proxied.
```

if you write location 1 some like

```
location ~ ^/browser/.*/welcome/.*\.(js|css)$
```

check

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3002/browser/KEY/welcome/some/path/file.js
Not proxied.

$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3002/browser/KEY/welcome/some/path/file.txt
Proxied from 127.0.0.1

$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3002/browser/KEY/notwelcome/some/path/file.txt
Proxied from 127.0.0.1
```

if swap location 1 and 2 all request will match only with

```
location ~ ^/browser/.* {
```

and will be proxied

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3002/browser/KEY/some/path/file.css
Proxied from 127.0.0.1
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3002/browser/KEY/welcome/asdfadfasdfas.txt
Proxied from 127.0.0.1
```

> [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)
> Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance
> in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions
> terminates **on the first match**, and the corresponding configuration is
> used.